# How to use a Roslyn scripting submission as an assembly in other Roslyn compilations

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, roslyn

I'd like to reuse a script as a dynamic assembly in another non-scripting Roslyn compilation, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make that work.

For example, say a I create a script the normal way and then emit the script as an assembly to a byte stream using something like:

```
var compilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
var compilation = script.GetCompilation().WithOptions(compilationOptions);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
}
```

Now, let's say I want to feed that assembly into another non-scripting compilation as a reference. I can't just use the `assembly` since none of the `MetadataReference.CreateFrom...()` methods support passing an actual `Assembly` instance. As a dynamic assembly it doesn't have a location so I can't use `MetadataReference.CreateFromFile()`.

In the past I've used `MetadataReference.CreateFromStream()` for this type of thing with success, but that doesn't seem to work when the assembly represents a script submission (I have no idea why). The compilation proceeds, but as soon as you attempt to use a type from the submission you get errors like:

```
System.InvalidCastException: [A]Foo cannot be cast to [B]Foo. Type A originates from 'R*19cecf20-a48e-4a31-9b65-4c0163eba857#1-0, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' in a byte array. Type B originates from 'R*19cecf20-a48e-4a31-9b65-4c0163eba857#1-0, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' in a byte array.
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the submission assembly being in a different context when evaluating vs. loaded as a byte array. I'd love any insight or guidance into the best way to use objects and methods defined in a script submission in later non-script compilations.

**Update 7/29**

I was able to get a minimal repro that demonstrates the problem. It can be found at https://github.com/daveaglick/ScriptingAssemblyReuse.

In producing the repro, it became clear that an important component of this problem is that the script passes the `Type` of one of it's classes out to the calling code, the calling code then uses that `Type` to instantiate an instance of the object, and then passes the instance into the compilation that references the script assembly. The mismatch happens when casting from the instance of the type created by the host application to the type from within the referencing compilation. As I re-read that it sounds very confusing, so hopefully the code below will make it clearer.

Here's all the code to trigger this problem:

```
namespace ScriptingAssemblyReuse
{
    public class Globals
    {
        public IFactory Factory { get; set; }    
    }

    public interface IFactory
    {
        object Get();
    }

    public class Factory<T> : IFactory where T : new()
    {
        public object Get() => new T();
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }

        private Assembly _scriptAssembly;

        public void Run()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;

            // Create the script
            Script<object> script = CSharpScript.Create(@"
                public class Foo { }
                Factory = new ScriptingAssemblyReuse.Factory<Foo>();
                ", ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(IFactory).Assembly.Location)), typeof(Globals));

            // Create a compilation and get the dynamic assembly
            CSharpCompilationOptions scriptCompilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
            Compilation scriptCompilation = script.GetCompilation().WithOptions(scriptCompilationOptions);
            byte[] scriptAssemblyBytes;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                EmitResult result = scriptCompilation.Emit(ms);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                scriptAssemblyBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
            _scriptAssembly = Assembly.Load(scriptAssemblyBytes);

            // Evaluate the script
            Globals globals = new Globals();
            script.RunAsync(globals).Wait();

            // Create the consuming compilation
            string assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            CSharpParseOptions parseOptions = new CSharpParseOptions();
            SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
                public class Bar
                {
                    public void Baz(object obj)
                    {
                        Script.Foo foo = (Script.Foo)obj;  // This is the line that triggers the exception 
                    }
                }", parseOptions, assemblyName);
            CSharpCompilationOptions compilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
            string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
            CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(assemblyName, new[] {syntaxTree},
                new[]
                {
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "mscorlib.dll")),
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.dll")),
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Core.dll")),
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Runtime.dll"))
                }, compilationOptions);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(scriptAssemblyBytes))
            {
                compilation = compilation.AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromStream(ms));
            }

            // Get the consuming assembly
            Assembly assembly;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                byte[] assemblyBytes = ms.ToArray();
                assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);
            }

            // Call the consuming assembly
            Type barType = assembly.GetExportedTypes().First(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Bar", StringComparison.Ordinal));
            MethodInfo bazMethod = barType.GetMethod("Baz");
            object bar = Activator.CreateInstance(barType);
            object obj = globals.Factory.Get();
            bazMethod.Invoke(bar, new []{ obj });  // The exception bubbles up and gets thrown here
        }

        private Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            if (_scriptAssembly != null && args.Name == _scriptAssembly.FullName)
            {
                // Return the dynamically compiled script assembly if given it's name
                return _scriptAssembly;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @EliArbel The application is pretty complicated, so I'm attempting to distill it down to a more simple repro. I'm having difficulty getting the exact InvalidCastException noted above and am instead getting a TypeLoadException when I attempt to use a type from the submission in the consuming compilation. I find this interesting, and possibly related. The repro I have so far is here: https://github.com/daveaglick/ScriptingAssemblyReuse

Comment: @EliArbel I've added sample code in both the linked GitHub repo and up above

Comment: Any reason you didn't just use a compilation-to-compilation reference?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski That's actually what I had been doing, and it worked great. I was attempting to switch to the scripting engine for the first bit to take advantage of the way it automatically promotes inline classes, methods, etc. out of the script method and into/alongside the container class. I never did get the scripting engine to work due to this problem, but I was able to get what I was after with a compilation-to-compilation reference by compiling with the `Script` source kind and then using a walker to visit the top nodes in the tree and extract promotable ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've solved the mystery. Here's what happens:

- Create a script.
- Get the script's compilation, but override the compilation options. Specifically, it uses the default `ScriptClassName`, which is `Script` rather than the one generated by the scripting API (e.g. `Submission#0`) - **this is the crux of the matter**.
- Emit an assembly using the overridden options & load it into memory from the stream.
- Run the script. At this point there are **two distinct** and incompatible assemblies with the same name in loaded into the `AppDomain` using byte arrays.
- Add the stream as a metadata reference to a new compilation and use it in code. It compiles fine since it's using the assembly generated from overridden options. You would not be able to compile it using the actual assembly created by the script, since **names like `Submission#0` are illegal in C#**. If it weren't then you could put the actual script `Assembly` instance in the globals and use it in `OnAssemblyResolve`.
- Call method `Baz` with a parameter of type `Submission#0+Foo` and try to cast it to `Script+Foo`.

To conclude - I don't believe this is possible using the current Roslyn Scripting API. However, these APIs are not the only way to compile scripts. You can just create a compilation on your own and set the `SourceCodeKind` to `Script`. You'd have to do a lot yourself, like running the main script method, handling globals, etc. I've done something like this [in RoslynPad](https://github.com/aelij/RoslynPad/blob/master/src/RoslynPad.Roslyn/Scripting/ScriptRunner.cs) because I wanted the script assemblies to load with PDBs (so exceptions would have line information).

Comment: Ah, ha! That makes sense. If I understand, you're saying it only replaces the scripting container class name when you build the compilation, so when you just evaluate the script anything inside it is contained in a different class (that also happens to be illegal in C#).

The ironic thing is that I was trying to port some code away from my own "script host" to the scripting engine (primarily to make use of the cool way it "lifts" classes and methods to the containing class). Looks like I'll be going back to a custom-rolled scripting solution for now.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Gotcha, and because I can't supply an alternate `CSharpCompilationOptions` to the normal script runner they'll never have the same name. On second thought - there may even be a way to work around this. If I don't ever use the `Script<T>.RunAsync()` method and instead *only* eval the script from the emitted assembly using reflection, it might work. May need a little scaffolding, but that'd be easy enough to copy from the Roslyn source. At least now I know where to look.

Comment: Yeah, I had been doing everything without getting scripting involved. It's actually much more performant that way - and all this referencing stuff worked fine. The one thing I like the scripting APIs for is to recognize inline classes, methods, extension methods, etc. and place them in the outer container class - that turns out to be really, really hard to do just from the SyntaxTree because it gets so confused with mixed code and stuff that should be lifted.

Comment: Oh, crap. That means I spent two days going in circles FOR NOTHING! :)

Comment: I'll give that a shot with the old code, it'd be preferable if it works.

Comment: Is there an example where compiling an assembly and using it in CSharpScript works? Thanks!