# C# Roslyn to use previously compiled class in next compilations

Tags: c#, roslyn, in-memory, runtime-compilation

I ask with example,
Lets say I have the following code.

```
fullcommand = @"public class oldTest
{
    public static void oldTestMethod(){
        Console.WriteLine(""oldTest Class"");
    }
}"

var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(fullCommand);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                assemblyName,
                new[] {syntaxTree},
                references,
                options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,allowUnsafe:true));

var ms = new MemoryStream();
var result = compilation.Emit(ms);
```

And I will compile the above code with Roslyn in memory.
next i want to compile another code in memory to use the above compiled class, lets say the below.

```
new_fullcommand = @"public class newTest
    {
        public static void newTest(){
            oldTest.oldTestMethod();
        }
    }"

    var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(new_fullcommand);
    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                    assemblyName,
                    new[] {syntaxTree},
                    references,
                    options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,allowUnsafe:true));

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var result = compilation.Emit(ms);
```

how can i make the second code to use the first code as its reference? or use it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to pass in multiple `syntaxTree` objects when you create your compilation.

However, if you want to build up your compilation incrementally I believe you can use [`Compilation.AddSyntaxTrees`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/Compilation.cs,2fe37ae8e9f4cbe1) to your first `compilation` object.

Comment: I cant do that, I need to compile SyntaxTrees separately because i am not aware of upcoming codes.

Comment: I found this pretty much relevant, but i cant get it work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646619/how-to-use-a-roslyn-scripting-submission-as-an-assembly-in-other-roslyn-compilat
Any idea how to fix it?